# Access denied when running attrib command

Tags: command-line, cmd.exe

My files on my USB drive are hidden. When I used the `attrib` command in a Command Prompt to unhide them, it said:

```
Access denied - D:\System Volume Information
```

[image]

How can I fix this?

Comment: So what is your question?

Comment: I cant see my files inside my USB. can you help fix?

Comment: System Volume Information folder is a special hidden folder owned by Windows OS. You should have never need anything to do with it (or even tried to change the attribute of that folder).

Comment: @Gareth: If you’re going to edit posts to embed images, would you please use the conventional style?

Comment: @Scott: I normally do (I do a ton of edits - see here: http://superuser.com/users?tab=Editors&filter=all ). I must have missed this one. Thanks.

Answer (score -1):

I would recommend using "cacls" command to get the permission (forced). For example:

```
cacls "System Volume Information" /p username:f
```

- `/p`: means replacing the specified user's access rights
- `f`: means full control

Note that other users will no longer be able to access that folder.

If you are successful, you can do whatever you want to that folder. This command can also be used to control access to your personal files and folders, and is pretty difficult to overwrite.